# How to stop a timer in android studio and then start again from when it was stopped?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, timer

**I am making a Pomodoro TImer app. I've already implemented the play and stop functions. Now I'm trying to implement the pause function. When I press the pause button, it successfully pauses the timer, but, when I press the play button once again, it restarts from 25:00 and not from the time I stopped at. How do I implement this method?**

Code below:

```
package com.example.treeplanting;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public class Pomodoro extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView tvTimer, tvMotivationalQuote;
    private ImageView ivStop, ivPause, ivPlay;
    private SeekBar seekBar;

    private CountDownTimer countDownTimer;
    private boolean isRest = false;
    private int userSelectedDuration = -1;

    private final int ONE_SECOND_TICK = 1000;
    private int counter = 0;

    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_pomodoro);

        tvTimer = findViewById(R.id.tvTimer);
        tvMotivationalQuote = findViewById(R.id.tvMotivationalQuote);
        ivPlay = findViewById(R.id.ivPlay);
        ivStop = findViewById(R.id.ivStop);
        ivPause = findViewById(R.id.ivPause);

        seekBar = findViewById(R.id.seekBar);

        tvMotivationalQuote.setText(MethodsContainer.getMotivationalQuote());

        // Setting up Seek Bar

        seekBar.setMax(2500);
        seekBar.setProgress(1500);
        seekBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        tvTimer.setText("25:00");
    }

    // On click methods

    public void startTimer(View v){
        ivPlay.setClickable(false);

        isRest = false;
        int duration = seekBar.getProgress();
        userSelectedDuration = duration;
        restartTimer(duration);

        ivStop.setClickable(true);
    }

    public void stopTimer(View v){
        ivPlay.setClickable(true);

        seekBar.setProgress(1500);
        tvTimer.setText("25:00");

        ivStop.setClickable(false);
    }

    public void pauseTimer(View v){
        if(countDownTimer != null) {
            countDownTimer.cancel();
        }

        ivPlay.setClickable(true);
    }

    // Update methods

    private void updateTimer(int progress){
        int minutes = progress / 60;
        int seconds = progress - minutes * 60;

        String textMinutes = String.valueOf(minutes);
        String textSeconds = String.valueOf(seconds);

        if(seconds < 10) textSeconds = "0" + textSeconds;
        if(minutes < 10) textMinutes = "0" + textMinutes;

        tvTimer.setText(textMinutes + ":" + textSeconds);
    }

    private void restartTimer(int duration){
        countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(duration) + 100, ONE_SECOND_TICK) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                updateTimer((int) millisUntilFinished / 1000);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                breakTimer();

                counter = counter + 1;

                mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(Pomodoro.this, R.raw.alarm);
                mediaPlayer.start();
            }
        };

        countDownTimer.start();
    }

    private void breakTimer(){
        isRest = !isRest;


        if(isRest){
            seekBar.setProgress(300);
            tvTimer.setText("5:00");
            restartTimer(300);
        } else{
            restartTimer(userSelectedDuration);
        }
    }
}
```

****Output: 25:00 -> 24:05 (I press pause button, it stops...) -> I press the play button -> 24:59
  Expected Output: 25:00 -> 24:05 (I press pause button, it stops...) -> I press the play button -> 24:04**
**

Comment: What variable are you trying to store the time in? It seems like you are using the countDownTimer variable to do that, but you set it to null in pauseTimer.

Comment: I deleted countDownTimer = null;

Comment: Please make the change in your post as well, and verify that the app still doesn't work properly.

Comment: Done. Help me pls

Comment: You are tracking the amount of time left using `countDownTimer` but instantiate a new `CountDownTimer` class every time you restart the timer.

Comment: Look at each time you call `restartTimer`. You always restart it with a constant time or the user selected time instead of the remaining time.

Comment: I get where I made the mistake. But how can I calculate the remaining time?

Comment: One way would be to create a global variable and update it in your `onTick` method using the `millisUntilFinished` variable. Then you can use the global variable to restart the timer.

Comment: Thank you very much sir! It finally works. God bless you

Answer (score 0):

check this outfor help on developing a countdown timer app:

https://github.com/harish124/Android_Data_Binding/tree/master/AlarmClock